# Question about Royden's proof about measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading the following proof(Lemma 11) by Royden[image]

[image]

I would like to know why there is inequality instead of equality in the second last inequaility (the one that I circled and put a question mark beside).

Isn't it that $\Sigma(m^*I_n^\prime+m^*I_n^{\prime\prime}) = \Sigma l(I_n)$?

Note: $m^*$ denotes Lebesgue outer measure

Comment: IIRC, Royden's $m^*$ is *Lebesgue* outer measure. It is the case that each $m^* I_n' + m^* I_n'' = l(I_n)$ since $I_n$ is the disjoint union of $I_n$ and $I_n''$, so I think it can only be that he does not need equality, and doesn't feel like belaboring this detail; the inequality would hold even if $I_n' \cup I_n''$ were a strict subset of $I_n$.

Comment: @jdc doesn't  $m^*I_n^\prime+m^*I_n^{\prime\prime} = l(I_n)$ imply immediately that  $\Sigma(m^*I_n^\prime+m^*I_n^{\prime\prime}) = \Sigma l(I_n)$?

Comment: @jdc what do you mean by the detail?

Comment: Yes, since the sum is absolutely convergent, that does follow. The "detail" (sorry for the lack of clarity), I think, is that this is actually an equality, and it's a "detail" in that it's not strictly necessary for the proof. This part of the string of inequalities would go through even if for each $n$ we only knew that $I_n' \cap I_n'' = \emptyset$ and that $I_n' \cup I_n'' \subset I_n$.

Comment: @jdc is absolute convergence necessary in order for $m^*I_n^\prime+m^*I_n^{\prime\prime} = l(I_n)$ to imply immediately that  $\Sigma(m^*I_n^\prime+m^*I_n^{\prime\prime}) = \Sigma l(I_n)$?

Comment: Sometimes an author will put down only what is absolutely necessary for the proof. Then when they return to the subject in more generality the proof is identical to the one already known.

Comment: @user144840: No, that's more than I need. It might be relevant if we wanted to distribute the summation to $\sum m^* I_n' + \sum m^* I''_n$, but we're not doing this here. The reason I invoked this unnecessary hypothesis is psychological and rhetorical: absolute summability is sort of the gold standard for summability, so I mentioned it to indicate there was no question that the argument went through. Mathematical arguments after a certain level tend to stop dotting all the i's and crossing all the t's, and I'm afraid that's what I've done a bit here. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Royden probably copied that proof from somewhere that were dealing with outer measures in general. In general, you only have the $\sigma$-sub-additivity.